# How do I install “Slender” through Wine or PlayOnLinux?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I'm currently trying to install wine 1.5.9raw 3 in order to play 'Slender' through PlayOnLinux, but as I try to run it, my laptop says it cannot find that particular wine version. Can I download it externally and how can I apply it?

Comment: FYI: that version of wine is *ancient*.  You should probably use the latest Wine, unless you have a good reason to use the old one.

Comment: @DavidFoerster they said it can't find that wine version, which means they didn't install it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I don't think PlayOnLinux can do that, the last I checked, PlayOnLinux was smart enough to check the version of Wine that is latest stable.  In either case that's not their question.  Reread it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster the question doesn't ask how it's installed.  It simply asks "Can I download it externally and how can I apply it".  It does not specifically ask which method to install it, it simply asks that question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21023/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-thomas-w).

Answer (score 0):

Slender has a [platinum rating on WineHQ App DB](//appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26271). So its installation shouldn't be difficult and involve any additional step. No need to install a particular old Wine version.

### Install a Wine runtime

Install the most recent stable Wine version and PlayOnLinux:

```
sudo apt-get install wine playonlinux
```

### Install a Wine application

> 1. Open up PlayOnLinux and press on "Install".
>
>    [image: install]
>
>    Now in the bottom-left corner there is a little text saying "Install a .pol package or an unsupported application". Press that text.
>
>    [image: install unsupported]
>
>    Choose "Manual installation". Press "Forward".
> 2. Now choose "Install a program in a new prefix".
>
>    [image: install in new prefix]
>
>    Enter a name for your prefix, this shouldn't matter very much. Just enter something relevant to the game, without spaces!
> 3. Now you must locate the executable, usually this is a file named "setup.exe". But it could also be named "install.msi" or something similar. If you've downloaded the installer you should probably know where it is. When you've located the executable, press "Forward". Now there will soon pop-up a install window as it would have done on Windows. Just follow the applications installation instructions from there.
> 4. When the installer is done, press "Forward" and "Yes". Now you must locate the application. It is usually something like: Program Files/NameOfTheGame/Game.exe Press forward, enter the games name, and choose if you want any shortcuts. (The installer might already have placed on on your desktop!) If anything else pop-ups, press "No".
>
>    Congratulations, you are done!
>
> ### Running your application
>
> Most of the time you'll have a shortcut on your desktop or in your main menu. (Usually in "Other", or "Wine" if you have any category like that) If you don't you'll have to open PlayOnLinux and double-click the application you want to run.

([Source](http://playonlinux.wikia.com/wiki/Starters_Tutorial?oldid=3963#Installing_an_unsupported_application))